# Can I make react native project without using android studio?

Tags: react-native, android-studio, onedrive

I'm using onedrive from my school, and unfortunately I made my name of onedrive in korean(my country language). And It made lots of error in Android studio.. I can't start my react-native project since 2 weeks ago. Is it unpossible to make React-Native without Android Studio?

If It's not possible, I would buy another onedrive..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you have tried already, but you might try Expo. It lets you test your apps on a real device by scanning a QR code with the Expo Go Mobile App without manual building for iOS or Android.

[This article](https://medium.com/@no0law1/starting-a-react-native-app-w-expo-13680543e897) has some useful steps.

The official Website his [here](https://expo.dev/).

I also recommend not using OneDrive (if possible). You should use a [source control provider](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-git-and-how-to-use-it-c341b049ae61/) like [GitHub](https://github.com/) to store and save your code. This will solve all your problems with OneDrive, and it is free. It will also let you use Android Studio as long as your folders and files have their names in Latin/[ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) characters.

If you use OneDrive, you will run into problems with huge files taking up all of your storage after you build your app for the first time.

Comment: thank you!! I was discouraged and made new onedrive ..^^ :>